# Get CPU-usage (etc.) with Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

I want to read things like CPU usage, memory usage, etc. Normally, I would do that with a `PerformanceCounter`. But The assemblies for UWP don’t have that. So how is it done in Windows Universal Apps?

Comment: Damnit. I was going to suggest using [Windows.System.Diagnostics.ProcessDiagnosticInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.getforprocesses.aspx) but i just tested the API and it only seems to return details for your own package's processes when running in a WinRT app :(.

Comment: Any updates? Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @SepehrM No. But if you find one I’ll be glad to hear about it. (The user that commented before you is at Microsoft. Maybe he can find a solution.)

Comment: Any news on this @ispiro?

Comment: @mayu No. I tried the answer below, but it doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use native calls and pinvoke.  see my other post.  stilling searching for libraries for cpu usage, but memory usage and cpu info is handled in this post

[summarizes both SO post (Microsoft forums)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1e99785-f8bb-41b3-bb53-d8c13dc38696/system-statistics?forum=wpdevelop)

[Basic pinvoke - SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728944/hello-world-for-pinvoke-and-native-calls)

[Diagnostic stat with pinvoke - SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708279/how-to-get-diagnostic-statistics-from-a-uwp-app)

Comment: Thanks.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​