# Need to retrieve System disk & memory usage data within Universal Windows 10 Platform App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, system.diagnostics

I am working on an app that has a "feedback" capability, and in that capability I would like to capture the system's disk and memory usage for the user to voluntarily submit along with their feedback. An example of what I am looking to display is:

```
Memory Usage: 682.56/2048 MB (33.33% free)
Disk Usage: 4.90/11.75 GB (41% free)
```

I have read through the MSDN's documentation on System.Diagnostics, and cannot find any information relevant to UWP 10. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I‘m afraid you can not get system disk and memory usage in an UWP app, as you can see, you can only get app memory usage using [AppMemoryReport class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.appmemoryreport.aspx).

Comment: the device portal emits the data: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P461 Look if you can parse them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your only option AFAIK, is to use native calls/Pinvoke

see here for examples and calls
http://www.pinvoke.net/

and here
[Hello World for Pinvoke and Native Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728944/hello-world-for-pinvoke-and-native-calls)

the only problem is that your are not allowed to use these if your going to submit your app to the store (need to side load it)